# Laravel acces denied for connecting db

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, connection, homestead

I have started laravel recently, and I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email` = ***)
```

on a clean freshly made project when I try to register with the default auth system. `php artisan migrate` works well, and I can connect to the database through mysql workbrench with the same credentials as in the .env file.

```
    DB_CONNECTION=mysql
    DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
    DB_PORT=3306
    DB_DATABASE=udemy-cms
    DB_USERNAME=root
    DB_PASSWORD=
```

I am using homestead with laravel, and mysql workbrench. I tried `php artisan config:clear` but did 
not help.

database.php is default

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: are you sure your config/database.php file uses the mysql driver?

Comment: looks like your username is incorrect in .env file if you are sharing real infos, `'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),` should be root if your database name and username are not same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would suggest to check if you can actually connect to your mysql using your current credentials. You should be able to connect to it in your command line like this:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

This basically tries to connect to mysql using root as a user with no password. If that does not work your user does not exist or your password is wrong.

If it works you should run following, to see if your database udemy-cms actually exists:

```
show databases;
```

If it does not show your database you need to create it.

```
CREATE DATABASE udemy-cms;
```

It is also possible that your user does not have enough permissions, in this case you need to grant your current user enough permissions.

Comment: The problem was that I used homestead with vagrant, and I used the local credentials, but not the virtual machines ones, thanks for all help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you updated the below values in your .env file

```
DB_CONNECTION = mysql

DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1" //ip or localhost

DB_PORT = "3306" //make sure its true one

DB_DATABASE = "your_database_name"

DB_USERNAME = "root" //is as default if you didnt create a new

DB_PASSWORD = "password" //or empty
```

Once updated `.env` file, and run command `php artisan config:cache` then restart the server of your project and serve the project again using the `php artisan serve` command

Comment: It is all good, I just figured out the problem is with the homestead, I didnt  set the database in the virtual machine